# Is Raspberry PI appropriate as gift for a non-english speaking person?

Tags: operating-systems

I am considering Raspberry Pi as a gift for an older Russian-speaking relative who is a computer enthusiast, but has a fairly limited grasp of the English language. What's involved in getting him a version of Raspberry PI with an OS installed with Russian as default language? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 3):

It should just be a question of using the internationalisation option of Raspbian.  The option should be presented when raspi-config is run.

raspi-config will run when Raspbian (the recommended OS) is first booted and may be run at a later time by entering the command sudo raspi-config.

There appears to be Russian language forum at http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewforum.php?f=84